How to set cursor position with tags file?
I am generating a tags file for m4 language. It works great, for example:
m4_symbol    k/applyforeachq.m4      /\m^m4_define\w*(\_s*«\?\zsm4_symbol\>/;
m4_symbol2   k/foreach.m4            /\m^m4_define\w*(\_s*«\?\zsm4_symbol2\>/;

However, the cursor always jumps to a random column position. I tried \zs or \%# or:
m4_symbol   k/applyforeachq.m4      /\m^m4_define\w*(\_s*«\?\zsm4_symbol\>/;/m4_symbol/;

but nothing works. Is it possible to set column position in tags files? Are there better ways for communicating symbols to Neovim?

According to :h tags-file-format there is a way to configure this using {tagaddress} field. Have you explored that option?

The third field /blabla/; is the tagaddress. My question exactly is what to put there. If theres anything more to explore, please point me to it.

I noticed that you don't include " in your term, which is supposed to be ;" (see :help tags-file-format). Could that be the problem?

If you really want to set the column, the only thing I can think of is /pat/execute 'normal! <col>|' (with execute to try to stop the bar from interfering with other notes on {term} in the format documentation)

@D.BenKnoble I noticed that you don't include " It is just a comment, I tried, it doesn't change anything. So I think my questin boils down, what ex command can I execute to position the cursor /\m^m4_define\w*(\_s*«\? {{HERE}} m4_symbol\>/ I tried /blabla/e-7 but it fails, neovim says such construct is not in tags file. Just tested, for example /blabla/|normal! 5| always results in  cursor in column 5.

Did you try the example from @D.BenKnoble? That should allow to place the cursor. You can use all kind of commands, like cursor() or search() or :norm! <col>| or similar. Restrictions apply see :h tag-security

@ChristianBrabandt yes, edited comment above. So I see search() starts at cursor positon and returns a line, I think searchpos() is more interesting, but thank you for direction! Is there a vimscript function to get the positoin of the latest matched // pattern? I think I wil try: position cursor at column 0, searchpos of the function, then position the cursor at column returned by searchpos. But I am  curious - how does ctags and others solve this?

Generate some tag files and see :) I think mostly they omit the column. I think I usually end up in column 0 when jumping with C-]

After the amazing help from @ChristianBrabandt I come up with the following:
m4_write        k/path.m4       /\m^\s*m4_define\w*(\_s*[`«]\?m4_write\>/|call cursor(0,stridx(getline('.'), 'm4_write')+1)

Works like a charm. I still would be courius if it is possible to simplify.
However, I also noticed that after pressing CTRL+] the 1st line 1st column shows in :jumps list, would be also great to remove it.
jump line  col file/text
  ....
  1     1    0

@edit The following fixes the 1st line problem. I believe that with / as the tagpattern, vim positions the cursor on the first line and adds it to :jumps list. Overall, the pattern is to just call appriopriate ex comand straight away.
suffix  k.m4    call search('\m^\s*m4_define\w*(\_s*[`«]\?suffix\>')|call search('suffix\>')


Don’t jump to the top, then. Maybe normal! 0 before searchpos (which can just be search)?

hi @D.BenKnoble I edited with something that moves curso only once. I think moving to top of the file is done by the ctrl+] vim system.

With just search, how can I position the cursor? search('\m^blabla <CURSOR HERE> blabla')?
